# Which of the following intervals contains integers satisfying the following three congruences:

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

**Question:** Which of the following intervals contains integers satisfying the following three congruences:
$x\equiv 2\pmod 5, x\equiv 3\pmod 7$ and $x\equiv 4\pmod {11}$,
(i) $[401,600]$, (ii) $[601,800]$, (iii) $[801,1000]$, and (iv) $[1001,1200]$

After solving I have found $x=2292\equiv 367\pmod {385}$. But this does not belong to any of the above option.  How can I find this solution?

Comment: @RossMillikan $2292$, and so $367,$ is a correct answer. Now, if $367$ is a solution then $367+385$ is a solution, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that there is no reason to focus on the smallest non negative solution.

Adding/subtracting an arbitrary amount of times the number $385 $ will yield other solutions. In fact, all of them, by the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: do you mean $367+385, 367+2*385$, in gengeral $367+r*385 $for $r\in \mathbf{Z}$? @ ArnaudMortier

Comment: @user584016 apart from the"$=0$", yes, I mean that.